# Interpretation of the azimuthal quantum number

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, hydrogen, orbitals

On the German Wikipedia [page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomorbital#Unterschale), we can read: "The higher the azimuthal quantum number $\ell$ for a fixed principal quantum number $n$, the more the average distance of the electron from the nucleus increases." Can someone explain to me why this is correct?

I thought that the average distance should decrease for increasing $\ell$ and fixed $n$, as
\begin{equation}
\langle r\rangle _{n\ell} = \frac{a_\mathrm{B}}{2}(3n^2-\ell(\ell+1)).
\end{equation}

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208024/2451

Comment: Since your formula is correct, the sentence seems incorrect to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the classical limit (the standard two-body $1/r$ potential problem), the energy of an orbit does not depend on the angular momentum:

$$ \epsilon \propto -\frac{\mu}{2a} $$

where $a$ is semi-major axis of the ellipse, and $mu$ depends on the interaction strength.

The state with highest angular momentum at fixed $a$ is the circle, and that spends *all* its time $a$ from the middle; meanwhile, as you approach zero angular momentum, part of the orbit approaches $r=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What do you think about the formula I have mentioned?

Comment: Looks good. Sometime classical analogs help, and sometimes they are totally wrong. See: http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~ohsean/361/Lectures/lecture17.pdf