# Why does the $2p$ orbital have lower energy than $2s$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, orbitals, lamb-shift

[image]

I know there already are questions about this. But I find some error there. So, I asked again....

The answers I have read mostly point out that electrons in 2s orbital have a higher probability to be near to the nucleus than 2p....and so they experience all the charge of nucleus, and shield the 2p electrons from experiencing it.

But, as the radial probability graphs indicate, 2p electrons have a lesser average distance from the nucleus than 2s. Also, the most probable distance of 2p is lesser the most probable distance of 2s. So, mostly, *2p* electrons would be *nearer* to nucleus. And so, shouldn't *THEY (2p electrons)* shield 2s electrons instead?

I am new to QM....so please give a satisfactory explanation.

Comment: Are we talking about hydrogen and a pure Coulomb field?  If so then $2p$ and $2s$ have the same energy: $-13.6/4$eV.

Comment: No, I am talking about multi-electronic atoms

Comment: As you move up the periodic table, the 2s shell fills *before* the 2p shell: the [electron configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration) for beryllium is $1s^2 2s^2$, while boron adds a p-shell electron. That suggests the 2s shell is the more tightly bound, lower-energy state, and the premise of the question is wrong.

Comment: Closely related: [Why are the higher angular momentum states of a hydrogen atom closer to the nucleus?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208024/)